# Create dependency for functions based on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning to use object literals. I couldn't find a solution for this...
There is an event fired by another application. Only if this event is fired, I want to execute some other functions (functionOne(), functionTwo()).
How can I create this dependency? Appreciate any help.

```js
var myObject = (function($) {
  var obj = {
    init: function() {
      this.eventCheck();

      // Only if eventCheck() returns true
      this.functionOne();
      this.functionTwo();
    },

    eventCheck: function() {
      document.addEventListener('appevent', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
    },

    functionOne: function() {
      // Do Something
    },

    functionTwo: function() {
      // Do Something
    },
  };

  return obj;
})(jQuery);

myObject.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery inside your function, why pass jQuery to it?. I made a snippet. Make it a [mcve]

Comment: Your method calls should go _into_ the callback function for `appevent` - there, were you are currently only logging the `e` object to the console.

Comment: It looks like `eventCheck` is a misnomer - it's current functionality would lead the function to be named `eventInit` or `setupEvents` or `addEventListeners`.   There's no "check" to return true/false (as provided).  it *appears* you want `functionOne`/Two to be called when the event *fires*, not during init.  The event itself will fire at a much later time, after init() has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this such way, since you don't wait the event and immediately call your functions.

Just call your function on the event:

```js
var myObject = (function($) {

  var obj = {

    init: function() {
      this.eventCheck();
    },

    eventCheck: function() {

      document.addEventListener('appevent', () => {
        console.log(e);
        // Only if eventCheck() returns true
        this.functionOne();
        this.functionTwo();
      });
    },


    functionOne: function() {
      // Do Something
    },

    functionTwo: function() {
      // Do Something
    },


  };

  return obj;
})(jQuery);

myObject.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your init function save the return value from eventCheck() function in variable and check if its return true then run other functions like this:

```
init: function() {

  var eventCheck = this.eventCheck();
  
  // Only if eventCheck() returns true
  if (eventCheck) {
      this.functionOne();
      this.functionTwo();
  }
},
```